# Post request doesn't send data to server using angular and php

Tags: php, angular

I want to send a post request from angular service to a php file so it can insert data to mysql on a xampp server. when i send call the function from the service nothing gets added to the server.

This is my service code I call the function in the type script

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient,HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators'
import { Epidemiologiques, Patient, Biologiques,Traitement, Cliniques } from './patient';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DonneesPatientService {
   private baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/gestipatient.php";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  postPatient(patient:Patient){
   
    this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}?func=Ajouter_Patient&nom=${patient.nomPrenom}&cin=${patient.cin}
    &profession=${patient.proffesion}&dateNai=${patient.DateNa}&sexe=${patient.sexe}&res=${patient.Res}
    &ville=${patient.Ville}&province=${patient.Province}&tele=${patient.Tele}`,
    { }).subscribe({ next: (response) => { /* Success action */ } });
  }
```

this is my gestipatient.php

```
<?php
require ("patient.php");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
$medecin =new medecin(0,"","","","");

if (isset($_GET['func'])) {
    $func = $_GET['func'] ;
} else {
    // Fallback behaviour goes here
}

extract( $_GET);
extract( $_POST);
if($func ='Ajouter_Patient') $medecin->addPatient($nom,$cin,$profession,$dateNai,$sexe,$res,$ville,$province,$tele);

?>
```

and this is my patient.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
function connect(){
    $con =null;
    try{
        $con=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=chu","root","");
    }catch(Exception $e){}
    return $con;
}

class medecin{
    public $idmed;
    public $nomed;
    public $prenommed;
    public $login;
    public $motdepasse; 
    public function __construct($i,$n,$p,$l,$m)
    {
        $this->idmed=$i;
        $this->nomed=$n;
        $this->prenommed=$p;
        $this->login=$l;
        $this->motdepasse=$m;
    }
    public function addPatient($nom,$cin,$profession,$datedenaissance,$sexe,$residance,$ville,$province,$tele)
    {
        $result;
        $con=connect();
        if($con!=null)
        {
        $con->query("insert into `patient`(`Nom`,`Prenom`,`CIN`,`Profession`,`Date de naissance`,`Sexe`,`Residance habituelle`,`Ville `,`Province`,`Telephone`)
        values('".$nom."','".$nom."','".$cin."','".$profession."', '".$datedenaissance."','".$sexe."','".$residance."', '".$ville."','".$province."','".$tele."');");
        $result = array("result" => "Success");
        echo json_encode($result);
        }else{
        $result = array("result" => "Failure");
        echo json_encode($result);
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
class patient{
    public $idp;
    public $nom;
    public $prenom;
    public $cin;
    public $profession;
    public $datedenaissance;
    public $sexe;
    public $residance;
    public $ville;
    public $province;
    public $tele;
  
    public function __construct($i,$n,$p,$c,$pr,$d,$s,$r,$v,$pro,$t)
    {
        $this->idp=$i;
        $this->nom=$n;
        $this->prenom=$p;
        $this->cin=$c;
        $this->profession=$pr;
        $this->datedenaissance=$d;
        $this->sexe=$s;
        $this->residance=$r;
        $this->ville=$v;
        $this->province=$pro;
        $this->tele=$t;
       
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Not a PHP developer, so cannot actually know what is happened in PHP. But from your Angular side, I don't see it will send a request to API. 1. You need to subscribe to observable in order to send the request. 2. Incorrect in assigning HttpParams. Should be: ``this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}+?func=Ajouter_Patient`,{ params: queryParams}).subscribe({ next: (response) => { /* Success action */ } });``

Comment: The first thing you need to do is check whether the request is sent by checking the browser DevTools --> Network tab. And also you may debug in PHP, set a breakpoint and see whether the PHP API side is hit.

Comment: you're not defining your PHP variables `$nom,$cin,$profession,$dateNai,$sexe,$res,$ville,$province,$tele`. You have to get them from the `$_POST`. And as YongShun said on the Angular side, you're request is not properly formed. You are making a using query params within the url, whereas a POST should use its body (your `{ }` empty param). Seems like you're confusing many things here.

Comment: can u explain more pls ? now it shows no error but still no data is sent.

Comment: @Random _"you're not defining your PHP variables"_ - they are using `extract( $_POST);` there, so although they rather _shouldn't_ be doing that, there will be a variable in that scope corresponding to every POST parameter that was sent.